# Smooth animation between two classes (font-family tag, in particular)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, smoothing

I'm looking to create the effect of a smooth animation between two different words and two different type faces. Ideally this would occur on click or hover, I'm not picky about that part of it. Basically, a smooth morph between two css classes.

I looked into the js .animate() function, but that is only for numerical values. I also tried MooTools [FX.Tween](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Fx/Fx.Tween) but that didn't seem to work either.

Think the Michael Jackson video for "Black or White", but with font-family.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is not possible at all in HTML. For an animation to be possible, JavaScript has to be able to calculate the steps in between - I don't think this can be done for a transition between typefaces.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that comes to mind:

http://raphaeljs.com/

http://raphaeljs.com/helvetica.html

If it can morph between different letters, with extra work it can do what you want.

Comment: ..or "Shape Tween" in Adobe Flash.

Comment: I was just about to recommend this. +1

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible because, as you said, animations must be performed on numerical values (background color, width, height, position).  You could only model font faces with really *complex* numbers.